# How can I edit a function from a package which is invoking UseMethod?

Tags: r, function, plm

I need to make some changes in `vcovG` function of the `plm` package. However, when I call `trace(vcovG, edit = T, where = plm)`, I get the following in the editor:

```
function (x, ...) 
{
  UseMethod("vcovG")
}
```

In the source code, the function is defined by the name `vcovG.plm`. But I call `trace(vcovG.plm, edit = T, where = plm)`, I get an empty function in the edit window.
Any ideas where I am going wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The method is not exported. Thus: `trace(plm:::vcovG.plm, edit = TRUE, where = plm)`

Comment: Are you looking for `getAnywhere('vcovG.plm')`? Or maybe `edit(getAnywhere('vcovG.plm'))`?

Comment: Thanks @Roland, `trace(plm:::vcovG.plm, edit = TRUE, where = plm)` works perfectly.